# How To Have Page Transitions on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a one page website, and I want to make it so when the user scrolls down animation plays and they are taken to the next section, like this site http://www.maman-corp.com/

I am having trouble on the scroll funtion, so that you are brought to the page and it doesn't allow you to continue untill the animation as finished.

I am also having the animations play over and over when you scroll, becuase it is seeing multipul scrolling acitions.

```
function scrolled(event) {
  var y = event.deltaY;
  var stopper = true;
  if(y>0 && stopper == true){
      stopper = false;
    $('.title').fadeOut(500);
    setTimeout(function() {
      var elmnt = document.getElementById("about");
      elmnt.scrollIntoView();
    },500);
      $('.title').fadeIn(500);
    setTimeout(function() { stopper = true;}, 2000);
  }
  if(y<0 && stopper == true){
      stopper = false;
      $('.title').fadeOut(500);
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("home");
    elmnt.scrollIntoView();
      $('.title').fadeIn(500);
        setTimeout(function() { stopper = true;}, 2000);
  }
}
```

EDIT:

I've tried to adding an if statemnt to see if it was animated, however I can't get the else to trigger, and it is always saing that it is animated, am I missing something about :animated ?

```
function scrolled(event) {
  var y = event.deltaY;

  if(y>0){
    if($('.title:animated')){
       //DO NOTHING BECAUSE ELEMENT IS BEING ANIMATED
       console.log('test');
   }
   else
   {
     $('.title').fadeOut(500);
     setTimeout(function() {
       var elmnt = document.getElementById("about");
       elmnt.scrollIntoView();
     },500);
     $('.title').fadeIn(500);
   }
  }

  if(y<0){
    if($('.title:animated')){
       //DO NOTHING BECAUSE ELEMENT IS BEING ANIMATED
   }else
   {
     $('.title').fadeOut(500);
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("home");
    elmnt.scrollIntoView();
    $('.title').fadeIn(500);
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question so we can provide the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your first problem but this will stop your animationg from happening on top of eachother. Calls an IF statement that checks if the element is animating or not before executing the code.

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
    if($('#your-element:animated')){
        //DO NOTHING BECAUSE ELEMENT IS BEING ANIMATED
    }else{
        //DO WHAT YOU WANT BECAUSE IT'S NOT ANIMATING ANYMORE
    }  
}
```